# What expression should I use after I have digressed and I want to continue with what I was talking about initially?

Tags: idioms

If I say "but I digress," then that indicates I have already digressed and I am finished. However, my concern is with the expression "if I may digress."

So suppose I am talking about tanks and it suddenly makes me think of a beautiful fish tank we had, but now I am done and want to say the digression is over. What is a professional way of doing it?
For example, should I say?

*Back to topic.

Anyway,....

Enough of that.*

Comment: Any of the above would usually work. How formal is the 'talk'?

Comment: If your audience is   n̶e̶r̶d̶s̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶g̶e̶e̶k̶s̶ computer literate, say that you're "*popping the stack*".

Answer (score 1):

A variant on the more common expression, **cut back to the chase** is also in reasonably common use according to internet searches. As the original metaphor is so widely known, the variant is transparent.

Supporting references for the original are easily obtained, for instance this from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_to_the_chase):

> "Cut to the chase" is a phrase that means to get to the point without
>   wasting time.
>
> The saying originated from early film studios' silent films. It was a
>   favorite of, and thought to have been coined by, Hal Roach Sr.

An example of the 'return to original topic' discourse connector, from [critic Mary Wakefield writing at The Spectator in 2017 {on a Patricia Cornwell publication}](https://www.spectator.co.uk/2017/03/a-new-ripper-mystery-why-wont-patricia-cornwell-stop-hunting-him/)
:

> 18 Mar 2017 – Cornwell herself is keen, in a polite but determined
>   way, to move from Scarpetta to the Ripper, so we cut back to the
>   chase.

It doesn't have quite the 'Let's stop beating about the bush' / 'Let's stop wasting time in digressions' / 'Let's get back to the point' senses or at least strong hints that some other re-orientation discourse connectors have.

I'd not use 'anyway', 'but I digress' or 'enough of that' in most contexts, as perhaps also hinting that the digression (which might have been at least as important as the main topic) was rather capricious. Unless I'm admitting I *had been* being a little self-indulgent. And I feel 'back to topic' has a flavour of 'I tend to be a little abstracted'.